# Disable Visual Studio's validation of non-xml files that look like xml?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a bunch of Velocity template files in a Visual Studio 2008 project, the problem is that despite the fact that the extension is `.vm` instead of `.xml` or similar Visual Studio thinks that the HTML they contains must conform to XML naming standards and generates errors (not just warnings even) on each compilation.

How do I tell Visual Studio to ignore these "faulty" XML files? I am willing to turn of all validation on XML but I have found no such option either.

**Update**, the errors don't stop the build they just drown the real errors behind about 20 validation errors. I seem to remember an option to turn off validation in VS 2005 but I can't find any such option in VS 2008.

I'm accepting adding `##` to the beginning of the file as answer, it does the trick even if it's ugly. Thanks Nir!

**Update 2** I thought I had tried your answer before Marc and found that it wasn't properly remembered. But now that I tried it again it does work very well, and it's cleaner than adding a comment to every file. Re-rewarding the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Xml errors usually only show if the file is open.

You can normally disable it by not opening it into the xml editor; the errors don't normally stop a build - they just look like they do.
Right click -> Open With... Source (Text) Editor  (or HTML if you prefer)
(and set as default).

Comment: -> Open With... -> 'HTML Editor' works great if you want to keep syntax highlighting and autocomplete.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I add a comment as the first line of the vm file, that way the file doesn't begin with a < and VS doesn't think it's an xml file.

Just add ## as the first line of every file then close and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: right-click on a .VM file, select Properties. There you can change the Build Action, you might want to set it to either Content or None.

Comment: The files currently have "None" as build action, and they are still validated. I was unclear in that the Errors don't stop the build though.