# How to selectively suppress markup validation in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, warnings, markup, suppress

Sometimes I find it useful to be able to suppress certain markup validation warnings within files that contain HTML (ASPX, etc.).

Is there an equivalent of `#pragma warning disable\restore` for HTML?

Comment: @downvoter, I'd appreciate a comment.

Answer (score 4):

There are similar questions around, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366426/html-doctype-for-includes-visual-studio-or-html-generic) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195293/disable-visual-studios-validation-of-non-xml-files-that-look-like-xml).

Unfortunately there is no solution to do it selectively. Only a global turn-off of the validation will hide those warnings.

Comment: Yes, turning it off globally seems to be the only way to hide warnings. I hope it gets implemented in the next versions.

Comment: Does this still appear to be the case? I'm getting warnings about nesting a 'div' element under a 'dl' element in VS 2019, which /should/ be allowed.