# HTML doctype for includes (Visual Studio or HTML generic)

Tags: html, visual-studio, include, doctype

Is there a doctype for **includes**, which tells validators (at design time, my IDE VS2010) not to check an included HTML fragment (or do a lenient check instead).

I have a main page ([which includes HTML parts with T4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359804/vs2010-disable-validation-for-particular-html-file-not-all-files)) such as options. The validator complains on the included html file, that `<optgroup>` cannot be on root level. This is correct, but not desired for an included file (just containing those options).

Could I give HTML a hint, not to check those things on the included file? The solution could be either **specific** to my IDE (VS2010) or **generic** (even better) as of the HTML standard.

```
<optgroup label="Africa">
    <option>North Africa</option>
    <option>South Africa</option>
</optgroup>
....
```

[image: VS2010 IDE validator]

PS: I prefer not to disable the checks completely (I know this can be done). It is not an option.

Comment: Why are your single template parts linked, so that a search bot could find them? You probably should exclude the whole template directory via a `robots.txt`.

Comment: It's the IDE complaining, and I talk about design time checks, not(!) browser checks.

Comment: There is no way in Visual Studio to configure/disable validation for just one file. If it bugs you: disable HTML validation for good...

Comment: What the hell is XHTML5 anyway? VisualStudio is weird...

Comment: @o.v. - From [the HTML5 spec section 1.6](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml): 'The second concrete syntax is the XHTML syntax, which is an application of XML. ... This specification defines version 5 of the XHTML syntax, known as "XHTML5".'

Comment: @Alohci: ah... not xhtml versions but *xhtml syntax* versions! I guess that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do those errors persist after installing [Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83)?

If you find it really annoying, you could always disable it completely under *tools -> options -> text editor -> html -> validation*

Comment: a) Completely disabling the checks is exactly what I not want
b) Thanks for the update: Scary one. Many people in the feedback section say, it crashes the css support. When I start the updater, it forces me to download SP1 of VS2010 first - which is already installed. Guess I have to make a complete backup first before I can try it.