# Disable Visual Studio's validation of non xml files that look like xml?

Tags: visual-studio, xml-parsing, visual-studio-extensions

This is a repeat of a question asked by someone else way [back in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195293/disable-visual-studios-validation-of-non-xml-files-that-look-like-xml)
, but it appears there was no real answer back then and this is still a problem.

I am writing a Visual Studio extension for files which look like XML but are not, and do not end in an xml extension. (I am using .csp) However Visual Studio continues to parse and highlight the file as if it was XML. This makes it difficult to get my own parsing and error processing to work.

Is there any way to programmatically tell visual studio that the file is not XML?

See also [similar issue on MS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/009f75f1-2c9c-4d8f-834a-3089fe7b565c/addin-vs-thinks-my-php-file-is-an-xml-file-and-messes-up-intellisense?forum=vsx&prof=required)

Comment: This is a bit of overkill, but have you thought about turning off intellisense? if you would like to do so , you can use the following for help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400939/how-can-we-disable-vs-2010-intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your own file extension, yes there is! It's simply a matter of editor priority. The XML-sniffer editor is only given a chance to claim the file if nobody else with higher priority does so first. It does so by registering the special `*` file extension as editable, then grabbing the file if it looks like XML -- but that `*` extension registration only has a priority of 33.

All you need to do is make sure *your* editor is registered properly with a higher priority. On your package, make sure you have the `ProvideEditorExtension` attribute. I suggest a  priority of 50 to start with (higher numbers have higher priority).

```
[ProvideEditorExtension(typeof(CspEditorFactory), ".csp", 50)]
```

If you don't already have an editor factory, there's a [good walkthrough on MSDN about how to create one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165071.aspx).